# How to disable or hide language change option in phpMyAdmin

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, centos7

I have setup a VPS with Nginx, PHP8.2, MariaDB and phpMyAdmin on CentOS7. All are working perfectly but a minor change I want to disable or hide language change options at phpMyAdmin login page for my users. I have done changes at **/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php** to force **'en'** as default language for all users. But I am unable to disable or hide language change options [ marked red at below image] at login page.

I have installed it by using  `yum --enablerepo=remi install phpmyadmin`

[image: Sample]

I have tried edited at both at **/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php** and **/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php** but no effect. Anybody kindly help to fix it.

Comment: Modify the login page template? Possibly templates/login/form.twig